# Wont use the proper file directory when using open()

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am trying to open a file using:

```
x = open(r'C:/Users/name/Desktop/bigfile.txt')
```

And it only looks through solution explorer so pretty much only inside of

```
C:\Users\ender\source\repos\Python Files Testing
```

I was searching the internet for two hours looking how I can look for specifically that file or even through all my files on the computer and I couldn't find anything that even remotely helped me I am using visual studio 2022 any help would be appreciated

Comment: A full path starting with the drive should work perfectly, people do it every day.  The only thing I can think of is that you don't have permission to access the file.

Comment: don't laugh, but depending on the os you're running, I've had issues with the direction of slashes. Try to mess around with back slashes or double slashes depending on your os.

Comment: The only situation I can imagine is using special characters for : and /, e.g., `f = open(u'D\uff1a\u2215test.txt', 'w')`.

Comment: Does it throw an exception?